# Migrate users from SP2007 farm to SP2013 farm on new domain

Tags: user-profile, cross-domain

I am working on a project, the requirement is to migrate the existing SharePoint 2007 farm (on Domain A) to SharePoint 2013 farm(on Domain B). Once SP2007 farm is migrated, the users should be able to access the new farm with old domain, i.e. Domain A. We are thinking of the following authentication options.

Kindly look into it and help us whether these options are technically feasible or not and some example migration projects.

Also, please provide us some links which help to migrate user profiles from SP2007 to SP2013.

Your help is very much appreciated!

Options:
 1. Windows Authentication(On-premise)

```
a. Client informed  us that there is a bidirectional trust between these 2 domains. We would like to propose to use the windows authentication in SP2013, as application can able to recognize users from both domains with trust.
b. The user profiles from SP2007 will be migrated to SP2013.
```

2. Claims Authentication(On-premise)

```
a. Considering future scalability, we would like to propose SAML token based authentication. So that it can be configured with different domain(s)/ADFS to authenticate users when there is any issue with establishing domain trust with other domains.
b. The user profiles from SP2007 will be migrated to SP2013.
```

Thanks

-Srini

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest breaking this down in to simpler steps, perform the domain migration as one step and then the 2007->2013 upgrade as a separate step.

I would recommend performing the domain migration first, I think it will be easier to domain migrate a SP2007 farm than a SP2013 one. The steps to perform this are listed here: http://blogs.technet.com/b/sushrao/archive/2011/12/02/sharepoint-migrating-sharepoint-server-from-one-domain-to-another.aspx. In your case I think you can ignore Step 7 as the users won't be moving domains.

Then you can just upgrade from SharePoint 2007 to SharePoint 2013, and this will automatically upgrade the user profiles etc. Note, there's no direct path to go from SP2007 to SP2013, so you'll have to upgrade to SP2010 first.